# Why does this code work on jupyter notebook but don´t work on a new python file?

Tags: python

Why does that code shows identation error when on a .py (Python) format and it runs smoothly when in a .ipynb (Jupiter Notebook)?

[Here is the image showing the error when I´m using the code on a new Python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96iWw.png)

[Here is the image when I run the code a new Jupiter Notebook file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Ggd.png)

I searched for identation problems all over the internet and I spent the last day only studying about the problems that arise from using tab and space for identation but it really doesn´t appear for me that it´s a tab and space problem since it work inside Jupiter Notebook. I activated the option to show all whitespace on my code so I can better pin down where is the problem but...I´m clueless.

I´m new to programming and learning a lot so can you send me some help on this?

Comment: Do not post text as image;

Comment: I don´t have enough reputation priviles for it, wish I could do it.

Comment: There is no reputation requirements to post text into a question.

Comment: Correct, but I was refering about your "Do not post text as image" that you commented.
So my answer to why I did that is because I don´t have reputation privileges to post an image, using the ! (exclamation mark) at the beginning of the image link to make it show as an image on my post. When I tried to do it and pressed save edit, I received an error message saying that I didn´t have enough reputation to make this kind of change.

Comment: This does not change anything. You posted links to images that show text. Just post your text into the question directly.

Comment: too much text, would not show the error messages for context. I don´t think it´s a valid point if I really want to show the whole problem. But thanks anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first photo *(Python file)*, looks like you haven't saved the file and maybe this can cause the error.

Comment: That made it work. Thank you very much!! I was having impostor syndrome already. Cheers comrade!